# How to wake up the host machine when client sent WoL packet to the guest machine run by vmware?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

How to wake up the host machine by WoL when client send WoL packet to the MAC address of network adapter inside the guest machine run by vmware workstation 16 player?

I want to let the host machine to sleep when my computer is not used. The client software is Steam Link. Steam Link automatically wake up computer by WoL when user tried to connect to the computer. I want to let run games on VM because my computer cannot be used, while Steam Link is used by my family. I already suceeded to run the game on the VM.

Host machine and guest machine are Windows 10 Pro.

I tried to achieve this by packet reley tools. run tcp/udp reley server on host machine with related port from host to guest. but steamlink could not wake up computer.

Comment: There won't be any way to do this from the host or guest machines since they'll be asleep.  If you have another physical machine on your local network, *maybe* you could have it listen for the WoL magic packet for the guest and then broadcast a WoL magic packet for the host.

Comment: That's good idea